# How to check if user input is an exact string I gave as an option

Tags: python, while-loop, user-input

The user has the choice if choosing a string. I just want to make sure the user picks the specific strings I provided.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
category_choice = input("Which category would you like to search with? Here are the choice: \n"
                        "'Name', 'Phone number','Class time','Class duration'\n")

while category_choice != "Name" or "Phone number" or "Class time" or "Class duration":
    category_choice = input("Please specifically write one of the choices of the list.\nInput: ")
```

Once the user input is correct, I want it to exit the while loop and continue, but it seems to go on forever.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write a string isolated, like 'Name' or 'Phone' or 'Other thing', the return value will be True, because `bool('anyword') == True, and bool("") == False`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
category_choice = input("Which category would you like to search with? Here are the choice: \n""'Name', 'Phone number','Class time','Class duration'\n")

while category_choice not in ["Name","Phone number","Class time","Class duration"]:
    category_choice = input("Please specifically write one of the choices of the list.\nInput: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the conditions:

```
while category_choice not in ["Name", "Phone number", "Class time", "Class duration"]:
```

or

```
while category_choice != "Name" or category_choice != "Phone number" or category_choice !=  "Class time" or category_choice !=  "Class duration":
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while category_choice != "Name" or "Phone number" or "Class time" or "Class duration":
```

Try to print this condition to check whether it returns true or false . While inputting ,only the first condition is checked ,for rest it assigns category_choice as "Phone number".

```
while category_choice != "Name" and category_choice != "Phone number" and  category_choice != "Class time" and category_choice != "Class duration":
    category_choice = input("Please specifically write one of the choices of the list.\nInput: ")
```

You should use and instead of or , because input value will always be "Name", "Phone number", "Class time", "Class duration".Let input be category_choice as "Name 'when it checks the condition using or that condition will always true ,because category_choice != "Phone number",similarly for other cases.

Hope it helps